# issue copying *.ink to desktop?

Tags: batch-file, copy, desktop

i would like to craete a batch file that copys my icon to the desktop, which is proving dificult can anyone help?

the code i have asumed to use is a simply xcopy but it dose not result as wished for

```
xcopy /s/y C:\ICT\AUTOCAD_2010\NEWINK C:\"Documents and Settings"\"%userprofile%"\desktop
```

thanks-

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
xcopy /s/y C:\ICT\AUTOCAD_2010\NEWINK "%userprofile%\desktop\"
```

In %userprofile% is the complete path, like "c:\users\Adam"
And the path "Documents and Settings" is only a synonym for "c:\Users"